# How to send scrapy request based on a given condition

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to send a Scrapy request to URL if the URL contains pagination, else I want to return the previous response from the prior request. I tried implementing that in the below code, but I am not getting the desired outcome.

so for example the url with and without pagination looks like this.

1. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/
2. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2021/results/

I sent a request to the 2nd URL because it contains pagination, and for the 1st, I just want to return the prior response.

I implemented that logic in the `process_link` function but I discovered that I only get a response from the 2nd link in the  `get_content` function.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.process_link,  
        meta ={
                'splash': {

                    'args' : {'wait': 0.5},
                     'endpoint' : 'render.html', 
                }       

            },
            dont_filter=True)    



    def process_link(self, response):

        
        next_page = response.xpath("//*[@id='pagination']/a[last()-1]//@href").extract_first()
        
        if next_page is not None:
            print('Check if next page is paginated------------------------------------',response.url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url= response.url, callback=self.get_content,meta = {
                'splash': {

                    'args' : {'wait': 5, 'lua_source': self.script},
                     'endpoint' : 'execute', 
         

                } },
                        dont_filter=True
                        )

        else:
            return response
            #     # yield SplashRequest(url=response.url, callback=self.get_content, endpoint='execute', args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': self.script,'timeout':90, 'images': 0, 'resource_timeout': 10}, dont_filter=True)


        
    def get_content(self, response):
        #Get the url for both request in parse_link function
        print('000000000000000000000000000000', response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `get_content` for your second case:

```
    else:
        yield self.get_content(response)
    ######### instead of #######
    # else:
    #     return response
```